# How to find and store all elements of a JSON array that have a certain key value pair

Tags: ruby, json

I am trying to parse JSON and extract some values to display.

The JSON format is:

```
 {
 "orders": [
 {
 ...
"order_number": 12345,
"status" : "processing",
...
```

I have this sample response in JSON parsed in `all_orders`:

```
response = http.request(request)
all_orders = JSON.parse(response.body)

# Checking for 'processing' orders...
processing_orders = all_orders["orders"].find{ |h| h['status'] == 'processing'    }['order_number']
```

I want to display the matching `order_numbers` that have the status of 'processing', however when I enter:

```
puts "processing_orders"
```

it is only printing one value, when I know for certain that there are more.

Is there something I am doing wrong? I am fairly new to working with this and have tried my best to try solutions on my own.

Comment: Is the `puts` string a typo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-find) for the `find` method:

> Passes each entry in enum to block. Returns the first for which block
>   is not false.

Find will only return one entry.

You want to use something like [`select`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-select) instead and then map to get the order number:

```
processing_orders = all_orders["orders"].select{ |h| h['status'] == 'processing'    }.map{|order| order['order_number']}
```

Comment: Excellent, that works very nicely! Thank you for that, I've been poking at it for an hour or so now.